# Ajax Random characters in text input by click button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is random **PHP** code:

```
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$length = 5;
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}//end loop
```

Form

```html
<form> 
  <input type="text" id="show_random">
  <button onclick="genCode()">gen</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is ur JS code ?

Comment: i want JS code function you can help me #thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com),

```
var genCode = function() {
  'use strict';

  $.ajax('/path/to/your/file.php', {
    success: function(response) {
      $('#show_random').val(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $length = 5;
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }//end loop
?>

<form> 
    <input type="text" id"first_textbox">
    <input type="text" id="show_random" value="<?php echo $randomString; ?>">
    <button onclick="genCode()">gen</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I want display id "show_random" after click button

Comment: What do you exactly need? the random code within the textbox with id "show_random" or anything else?

Comment: yes but i want random code within the textbox with id "show_random" after click button

Comment: for that only i asked you to put the value attribute there

Comment: this code is awesome, but i want to gen code by ajax i don't want to refresh my page #thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You may try the script below:

```
function genCode() {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        r.open("POST", "index.php", true);
        r.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
            document.getElementById("show_random").value = r.responseText;
        };
        r.send("");
}
```

Note: replace index.php on where your php code for random text is located.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js) lib first

```
    function genCode()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/your/file.php',
            success: function(response) {
              $('#show_random').val(response);
            }
        });
    }
```